# Preventing SQL injection without prepared statements/SQLite/C++

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection

I'd appreciate some feedback on how secure this scheme is against SQL injection attacks.

At the front end, the user enters personal information: name, address, phone numbers, email, and some freeform text.

The back-end is coded from scratch in C++, with no framework support, and integrates SQLite.

The C++ code does *not* use SQLite prepared statements (for historical reasons, and it's too late to do anything about it). Instead, all SQL statements are constructed as printf-style format strings, along these lines:

```
#define STATEMENT_N "UPDATE members SET FirstName='%s', Surname='%s', DOB='%s', etc"
```

The actual statements are created with a hand-coded `sprintf` (`sqlPrintf`) statement which handles only `%s`, `%c`, and `%d` conversions. The final statement is then created something like:

```
sqlPrintf(query_buffer, STATEMENT_N, user_str_1, user_str_2, etc)
```

So, in other words (if you're not familiar with C/sprintf), the user input is 'printed' into the `%s`, `%c`, and `%d`. The only non-obvious processing in `sqlPrintf` is that user-supplied single-quote characters are escaped (they're doubled up).

Is this sufficient to prevent SQL injection attacks? And is a 'prepared statement' actually anything more than the above scheme?

Comment: The best way to prevent SQL injection attacks is to use prepared statements.  You seem to know this.  Migrate your existing application to the appropriate technology for accomplishing what you need to accomplish.

Comment: no this is not good.  one of your types is %s.  that is just string.  what is the definition of an injection attack -- being able to insert arbitrary strings into the SQL code. THIS PROVIDES NO PROTECTION FROM INJECTION.  If you only allowed %d then maybe you would be ok.

Comment: 1.  No, this isn't enough.  What if my first name was `'; --`?  There's nothing in your code that would prevent that from being injected, and thus, wiping out everyone's first name in your table.  2. It's never too late to fix it.  3.  Yes, a prepared statement is much more than that.

Comment: the `sqlPrintf` doubles up user-supplied single quotes. If the name was `'; --`, then the statement becomes `SET FirstName='''; --'` - is that a problem?

Comment: I've just tried setting the first name to `'; --` using sqlite3, and it doesn't cause a problem (`update members set firstname='''; --' where id=931086`). It just set the first name as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the only thing you need to worry about here is the single quotes. Anything contained within single quotes in your query will be fine, but a lone single quote can end the string, allowing the rest of the data entry to run as code. If `sqlPrintf` doubles up single quotes, you should be fine. And reading the comments on your question, it sounds like this system works against the "';--" attack. :)

Answer (score 2):

Doubling single quotes is sufficient to prevent injection problems with strings. There are no other special characters recognized inside strings.
(Please note that SQLite already has [helper functions for this](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).)

If you ever need to handle blobs, you'd have to use parameters anyway. But that is a different question …

Comment: Great - thanks - spent hours on the docs but never saw the `sqlite3_xxprintf` stuff. My `sqlPrintf` is the non-existent `sqlite3_sprintf` with `%q`. Pity that `sqlite3_snprintf` is broken - that makes it of limited value. As an aside, I've not yet found any need for conversion specifiers beyond `%s` (`"%q"`), `%d`, and `%c`.

Comment: Why would I have to use parameters if I need to handle BLOBs? Why not just use BLOB literals? "BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'" —https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: Never mind. I found and thought of some reasons [why you should always use sqlite3_bind()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61164217/242933). But I guess if @QF0 really doesn't want to use prepared statements, then he could use BLOB literals if he ever needed to handle BLOBs.