# If my SQL statement is only evaluated once, then why would I use sqlite3_bind()?

Tags: c, swift, sqlite, prepared-statement

For example, the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761453/how-to-properly-escape-single-quotes-in-sqlite-insert-statement-ios#comment43934051_27761453) on the question [How to properly escape single quotes in SQLite insert statement - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761453/how-to-properly-escape-single-quotes-in-sqlite-insert-statement-ios) says "Don't use `stringWithFormat` to build your query. Do it properly with `sqlite3_bind_xxx` statements." I've seen (on Stack Overflow and beyond) many comments/answers like this that unconditionally suggest using parameters instead of literals.

However, I don't see any suggestions like that on the [SQLite website](https://www.sqlite.org/). I do see that section "[6. Binding Parameters and Reusing Prepared Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html#binding_parameters_and_reusing_prepared_statements)" in "[An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)" says that "SQLite allows the same prepared statement to be evaluated multiple times" by using [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

So if I'm only evaluating an SQL statement once, then why would I use parameters instead of just using literals (and when necessary escaping user-inputted text or converting data to BLOB literals myself)? Am I missing something here? I understand that "reusing prepared statements" and thereby "avoiding calls to [sqlite3_prepare()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) can give a significant performance improvement", but I'd like to keep my code as simple as possible for now and maybe enhance performance later.

Comment: *...and when necessary escaping user-inputted text...* why and how would you do that? Isn't it safer to let the Prepared Statement do it?

Comment: *"why would I use parameters instead of just using literals"* - Because it's safer to let the SQL engine handle the values than to try escaping/sanitizing them yourself.  There's also very likely to be a small performance improvement (may depend on the RDBMS) in keeping query structure and parameters separate, as the query engine will more explicitly know what's what when determining an execution path.  It's also a "good idea" in general to simply be in the habit of writing stable, secure, production-worthy code instead of asking "why bother".

Comment: @forpas, thanks. Why? Because it's easier and can be done with less code. How? See [Preventing SQL injection without prepared statements/SQLite/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001517/preventing-sql-injection-without-prepared-statements-sqlite-c). Why and how is it safer to let the prepared statement do it?

Comment: @David, thank you. Of course I want my app to work, but it seems simple enough and still safe to escape strings myself.

Comment: @ma11hew28: And in your attempt to make the code simpler, you are proposing: (1) Sometimes querying the database one way, sometimes another way.  (2) One of those two ways has extra operations (escaping the values).  (3) Having to remember which one was used where, and make sure you maintain that pattern going forward.  (4) Hoping anybody else working in the same code will understand it, otherwise have it explained to them.  (5) Developing coding habits you know you will want/need to change at a future time.  This is all simpler... how?  Just use the library how the vendor intends.

Comment: @David how do you know the vendor intends for me to always use [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html)? As I mentioned in my question, they seem to be suggesting that [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) should only be used if I want to reuse my prepared statement. What about statements that I only ever want to execute once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons to always use [sql_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

- It allows you to insert more data since SQLite limits the length of an SQL statement
- It's faster for a large string since it doesn't "need to be parsed or copied as much"
- It's faster and uses less memory for a large BLOB since converting data to a BLOB literal takes time and hexadecimal strings take up more memory than the data they represent
- It's advised in "[Limits in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)" under "[3. Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_sql_length)"

  > If an SQL statement is limited to be a million bytes in length, then obviously you will not be able to insert multi-million byte strings by embedding them as literals inside of INSERT statements. But you should not do that anyway. Use host [parameters](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) for your data. Prepare short SQL statements like this:
  >
  > INSERT INTO tab1 VALUES(?,?,?);
  >
  > Then use the [sqlite3_bind_XXXX()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to bind your large string values to the SQL statement. The use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the string, reducing the risk of SQL injection attacks. It is [*sic*] also runs faster since the large string does not need to be parsed or copied as much.

Note: I find the reason that "the use of binding obviates the need to escape quote characters in the string" insufficient on its own because doing that is easy enough to simply do explicitly either in my app's programming language or by using one of [SQLite's Formatted String Printing Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) with either the [%q or %Q substitution types](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html#percentq).

Answer (score 1):

"*when necessary*" is the key here. Being such open-ended, this approach will inevitably lead to SQL injection. What is user-inputted text? Is a part of the interface user-inputted? Is a text you have got from a database user-inputted? Can you guarantee that anyone working with the code base will have correct answers?

The data processing for SQL should be uniform and predictable. And prepared statements offer precisely that.

Besides, "escaping" is not intended for the protection. While giving you a false feeling of security it would betray you at the first opportunity. Try to protect a field name with string escaping and see. Unlike escaping, using prepared statements guarantee the protection, when applicable.

> I'd like to keep my code as simple as possible

For one, right now you've got the *coding process* unnecessarily complex, making yourself to ponder every time a query has be be executed, "is it necessary escaping user-inputted text or not?"

Finally, to simplify a repetitive task, there is a *user defined function* to the rescue. Just write a function that combines prepare/bind/execute in a single call and then use it to make your application code as simple and meaningful as possible.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So why not escape every value myself in my user-defined function? Wouldn't that solve all your concerns and save a bunch of code? For example, then my function could just call [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html).

Comment: *"it would betray you at the first opportunity"* - I wish I could upvote a second time just for that statement.  Even assumptions like "I'll only ever evaluate a SQL statement once" are only true up until the moment they're not.  Taking a step back, this whole question seems like an elaborate attempt of not wanting to type a few particular keystrokes (adding parameters as a separate argument), and going to *great lengths* to avoid typing them.

Comment: Thank you, both. Why would escaping a string betray me? One of the answers to [Preventing SQL injection without prepared statements/SQLite/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38001517/242933) says: "Doubling single quotes is sufficient to prevent injection problems with strings." Are you saying that's incorrect? I figured that's what [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) does under the hood. How does using [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) guarantee protection unlike escaping? How are they different, especially conceptually & performance-wise?

Comment: A string is not the only data type can be added to the query

Comment: @David, sure, but wouldn't preemptively architecting my code to reuse prepared statements be violating YAGNI? It seems to me that the main purpose of sqlite3_bind() is to allow me to reuse a prepared statement with different values. If I just need to escape a string, and I don't trust myself or my teammates to do that correctly, then couldn't I just use one of [SQLite's Formatted String Printing Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) with either the [%q or %Q substitution types](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html#percentq)? I'm just trying to learn the appropriate way to do things.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't see your point. Aren't strings the only datatype that I'd need to escape (by just doubling up single quotes)?

Comment: String is not the only data type **added to the query**

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, but I think a string is the only datatype vulnerable to SQL injection, and that seemed to be your main reason for using [sql_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). As far as adding other datatypes to an SQL query, a number can be added after converting it to a string, a `NULL` can be added after converting it to the string `"NULL"`, and data can be added after converting it to a BLOB literal (as I mention in my question). Anyway, I found and thought of some reasons and put them in a separate answer. Thank you, both, so much for challenging me on this. :-)

Comment: @ma11hew28 string is not the only data type vulnerable. Null is not a string, but a keyword. I don't really get what you're getting at

Comment: @YourCommonSense what other datatypes are vulnerable and how could they be exploited? Yes, but the SQL statement(s) passed to [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) (or to [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html)) is (are) represented as string(s). So to add `NULL` to an SQL statement, I'd need to represent `NULL` as a string. For example, let's say I'm coding in Swift and `x` is an `Int64?`. Then, I could construct an SQL statement like this: `let sql = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (" + x != nil ? String(x) : "NULL" + ")"` I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: why bother with a ternary if you can just bind a variable and it will be sent as null if null. Looks like you are trying to overcomplicate your code as much as possible

Comment: Note: In my last comment, `String(x)` should be `String(x!)`.

Comment: @YourCommonSense because 1) I find it easier and less complicated to just call [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) instead of [sqlite3_prepare()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html), [sqlite3_bind()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html), [sqlite3_step()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), and then [sqlite3_finalize()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) and 2) even if I did the latter, I'd still need to check if `x != nil` to know which sqlite3_bind_*() routine to call: sqlite3_bind_int64() or sqlite3_bind_null().

Comment: Anyway, @YourCommonSense, did you read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61164217/242933)? Also, have you read [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)? It says: "The [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) interface is a convenience wrapper that carries out all four of the above steps with a single function call".

Comment: All right I give up. I am impostor here actually, as I have no idea on Swift. In PHP we have got convenient libraries that take us only two calls, prepare and execute or w can write a userland function to encapsulate all the binding  inside and perform any query with parmeters in a single function call. Never thought Swift is such a tedious language to use.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, oh, OK. That's OK. Thanks for letting me know. That sounds nice. It looks like PHP's SQLite3 extension is a wrapper around the SQLite C interface, which was what I was asking about. Sorry for not making myself clear. I just added the c & swift tags to my question. Swift doesn't come with an SQLite library but lets you `import SQLite` (the C library) and [call imported C functions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift) directly. Anyway, thanks, all, for your help. :-)